# Naming data var passed trough jQuery method $.post

Tags: jquery, post, scope

I'm writing a `jQuery plugin` where I can send data trough `$.post` method and I would like to set the name of the var name passed via `ajax` object http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/:

```
$('#selector').pluginName({url:'url.com/searches', var_name:'myVarName'});
```

my problem is I can't set a name via `var_name` because it is passed as var name itself

```
var name = settings.var_name;
$.post(settings.url, {name:next_search}, settings.callback);
```

if I send this example i send `{'name':'data'}` instead of `{'myVarName':'data'}`.

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery Ajax method just takes an array for the data argument and there's lots of ways of creating that array.

If you want to add an item where the key is in a variable then you can add it directly.

```
var data = {};
data[settings.var_name] = next_search;
$.post( settings.url, data, settings.callback );
```

Comment: Isn't it an `Object` data instead of `Array`? http://docs.jquery.com/Post. I'm working with `CakePHP` and using this method gives me an empty array inside the controller.

Comment: if you look at the jquery docs it takes an array, and then serialises that into the post - when it hits the server it'll be individual variables on your controller

Comment: ps try using chrome/firebug and look at the network xhr requests going off to your server - you should be able to see the form post nicely to diagnose it

Comment: I checked the `XHR` data and with the `Array` don't send the data, using `{'data':'value'}` works, I just would find a way to pass a var name to the `{'varName':'value'}` to the object to send dynamically.

Comment: Just needed to change `var data = new Array();` with `var data = {};` this worked!

Comment: d'oh yep I should have spotted that!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17675/discussion-between-user1727088-and-vittorio-vittori)